# Ajax call with a PHP Redirect

Tags: php, ajax

How would I get my page to redirect when the form is submitted successfully?

Currently when the form is submitted with an error, the error appears above the form.

When the form is submitted without an error, the success page is shown INSIDE the error message container above the form (instead of redirecting).

My Ajax:

```
function checkform() {

var form = $('form')[0];
var data = new FormData(form);

    $.ajax({
      url: 'upload.php',
      data: data ,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      dataType: 'text',
      cache: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){
        $("div#error").html(data).slideDown("fast");

        //Scroll to top of this div - 70px from the top of your view, change this to whatever number you wish
        var destination = $('div#uploadContainer').offset().top - 15;
        $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({
            scrollTop: destination
        }, 200);
      }
    });
    return false;
}
```

My PHP (after the validation etc...)

```
if (isset($_POST['messageSubmit'])) {
    header('Location: ' . $message_location);
}

if (isset($_POST['drawingSubmit'])) {
    header('Location: ' . $drawing_location);
}

if (isset($_POST['postSubmit'])) {
    header('Location: ' . $other_location);
}
```

Comment: You should write location in success response

Comment: If you're trying to get the headers on success callback, you need to use *jqXHR* object: `jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Location')`

Comment: How would I state which redirection to use in the Ajax though? In the PHP, the redirection is decided by which submit button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect your page in your javascript `success` function, that is done with `window.location.href = "http://yourNewLocation"`.  In your case I would substitute the `onSubmit = "checkForm()"` with `onSubmit = "return false"` and in your input you can add `<input type="submit" name="drawingSubmit" value="Upload now" onClick = "checkForm('drawingSubmit')" />`. Now in your `checkForm()` function you can get the name of the clicked `input` as a parameter - `

```
 function checkForm(inputName){
    //current code 
       if(inputName == "drawingSubmit"){
          window.location.href = "//wherever you want to redirect the user";
       }
    }
```

Comment: How would I state which redirection to use in the Ajax though? In the PHP, the redirection is decided by which submit button is clicked.

Comment: When you call `checkForm` you can pass it a parameter with the name of the button. Depending on your current code you can use an `.on(' click', function(){...` event or you can pass the argument in the code if you have inline `onclick` function - `onclick = checkForm("messageSubmit")`

Comment: Is there a resource available for something like this? I don't understand.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp Show your code where you call `checkForm` so we can see what you should do

Comment: I changed the answer above, hope this helps

Comment: "hacky"? You need to return false to stop the form from submitting the normal way, thus reloading your page without keeping the js variables. Then we only invoke the same function, but with a parameter - you need the parameter to check which button was clicked. It is not the only way, you can also create a different function for each button and trigger it accordingly `.on('click', ...`

Comment: Where it says 'current code' does that mean all of the current JS code I have? So each button would be a separate script?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/D1EvhpPM

Getting: Uncaught ReferenceError: checkForm is not defined

Answer (score 0):

In the `success` callback function you must set the window location href like so:

`window.location.href = 'http://example.com/your-new-path'`